# Searching for specific words in a text string - SQL

Tags: sql, string, full-text-search, periscope

I wondered if someone might be able to help me. I know that I am doing something wrong and over-complicating this but i'm not sure what.

I would like to pick out text from questions 205,227 and 278 when someone uses the words Autism, ASD, Aspergers etc... to answer the question.

What is happening is I am only getting single word phrases, rather than when someone writes the word in a string e.g. 'I have autism' will not appear in the output. Only when someone writes Autism. I have noticed it is case sensitive too and I wondered whether this can be coded so that I don't have to write all words in every combination of upper and lower case.

The main things I need are the specific questions (question.id) and to be able to search for the occurrence of specific words and phrases within the responses of these questions (texter_survey_response_value.value).

```
    select 
    texter_survey_response.response_id, question_id, conversation_id, 
    texter_survey_response_value.value as scrubbed_feedback
    from
    texter_survey_response
    join texter_survey_response_value on texter_survey_response.response_id = 
    texter_survey_response_value.response_id
    where
    texter_survey_response_value.question_id IN (205, 227, 278)
    and texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Autism'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'ASD'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Autistic'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Aspergers'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Autism Spectrum'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Autistic Spectrum Disorder'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Autistic Spectrum'
    or texter_survey_response_value.value = 'Autism Spectrum Disorder'
    and texter_survey_response_value.value is not null
```

Comment: AND goes before OR. You need parentheses.

Comment: Thanks - It's working for the question.id but not searching for the words. I'll add it to the bottom of the query

Comment: You can use `IN` to simplify, e.g. `and texter_survey_response_value.question_id IN (205, 227, ...) and ...`

Comment: Feel free to ask follow ups if my answer didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `=`, it will only search for exact matches. You can achieve a contains-search with `like` by adding `%` to both sides of your search phrases. You can work around the case-sensitive nature of most `like` implementations by only working with upper or lower case.

```
select 
  texter_survey_response.response_id, question_id, conversation_id, 
  texter_survey_response_value.value as scrubbed_feedback
from
  texter_survey_response join texter_survey_response_value
    on texter_survey_response.response_id = texter_survey_response_value.response_id
where
  texter_survey_response_value.question_id IN (205, 227, 278)
  and texter_survey_response_value.value is not null
  and (
    UPPER(texter_survey_response_value.value) like '%AUTISM%' or
    UPPER(texter_survey_response_value.value) like '%AUTISTIC%' or
    UPPER(texter_survey_response_value.value) like '%ASPERGERS%' or
    UPPER(texter_survey_response_value.value) like '%ASD%');
```

You didn't write what database you use, so you might have to call a different procedure than `UPPER`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help. That's great.