# SQL Subquery - How do I get this to work - MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to create a subquery. I am trying to find the value of question 66 for the subset of people who answered with any of the following phrases (e.g. 'Autism') to questions 205/227/278.

I can't seem to get this to work, would someone be able to advise where I am overcomplicating or going wrong with this?

```
select texter_survey_response.conversation_id
from texter_survey_response
join texter_survey_response_value on texter_survey_response_value.response_id = 
texter_survey_response.response_id
where texter_survey_response_value.question_id = 66
  (select texter_survey_response_value.value
  from texter_survey_response_value
  where texter_survey_response_value.question_id IN (205, 227, 278)
  and texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Autism%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%ASD%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Autistic%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Aspergers%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Asperger%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Autism Spectrum%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Autistic Spectrum Disorder%'
  or texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Autistic Spectrum%')
```

I am working with SQL on Periscope (MySQL).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to put parenthesis around your `texter_survey_response_value.value ilike '%Autism%'
  or texter_survey_respo...` ? So the opening after the `and` and the closing one right before your last closing one?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771085/searching-for-specific-words-in-a-text-string-sql?

Comment: As @jarlh suspected, you already asked this question before:  [Searching for specific words in a text string - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771085/searching-for-specific-words-in-a-text-string-sql)

Comment: @jjdata please explain ? Why are there two questions?

Comment: I am asking different questions here. In this question I am asking about how I can create a subquery. In the other question I needed help with the cases. I wasn't aware I was not able to separate two questions. I have been finding it confusing. If I am not allowed then I will remove this question. Thanks

Comment: I have now broadened what I am trying to find, after being assisted with the other query.

Comment: You may skip a half of your ILIKEs. For example, each record for `ilike '%Autistic Spectrum%'` is already found by `ilike '%Autistic%'`...

Comment: Ok @jjdata but you have to understand that people do not see that. You have said thanks to the person who answered your old question and you have to accept it if it is closed... And then move to the new question

Comment: I don't know how to close the other question. I wasn't aware. I will look into that now. When people are new to Stack Overflow and asking for assistance, they sometimes need some support with how to use the forum also. Thanks

Comment: @Akina sorry, I see you have already mention the duplicates in your comment.

Comment: @jdata . . . MySQL does not have `ilike`.  Are you sure you are not using Postgres?

Comment: Thanks, I have amended my other question.

Comment: I am using MYSQL on Periscope and ilike appears to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of the mistakes in your query is here:

```
where texter_survey_response_value.question_id = 66
  (select texter_survey_response_value.value
```

Please try to explain what do you plan to do here, compare `exter_survey_response_value.question_id`  with `66` or with the result of the subquery ?

**Also I have noticed you are using keyword ilike and not like!!**

Next that I have noticed is that some of the like lines can be turn into one line:

```
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Aspergers%'
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Asperger%'
```

And this also:

```
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autistic Spectrum Disorder%'
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autistic Spectrum%'
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autistic%'
```

And this:

```
texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autism%'
texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autism Spectrum%'
```

**As Akina already commented on your question...**

So all of this 7 lines of code can be replace with:

```
texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autism%'
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Autistic%'
or texter_survey_response_value.value like '%Asperger%'
```

And when you answer me to my question from the top of this answer I can help you more...

Also you can use aliases for your tables and you should use `IN` operand to compare value with the multiple values you will get from the subquery.

```
select tsr.conversation_id
from texter_survey_response tsr
join texter_survey_response_value tsrv on tsrv.response_id = tsr.response_id
where tsr.question_id = 66
and tsrv.value in
(select tsrv1.value
 from texter_survey_response_value tsrv1
 where tsrv1.value like '%Autism%'
 or tsrv1.value like '%Autistic%'
 or tsrv1.value like '%Asperger%')
```

Also I do not see a need for subquery. You can do it like this:

```
select tsr.conversation_id
from texter_survey_response tsr
join texter_survey_response_value tsrv on tsrv.response_id = tsr.response_id
where tsr.question_id = 66
and tsrv.value like '%Autism%'
 or tsrv.value like '%Autistic%'
 or tsrv.value like '%Asperger%';
```

After some chat discusion with the OP I have wrote this query:

```
select tsr.conversation_id
from texter_survey_response tsr
join texter_survey_response_value tsrv on tsrv.response_id = tsr.response_id
where tsrv.question_id = 66
and tsrv.response_id in (select tsrv2.response_id
                         from texter_survey_response tsr2
                         left join texter_survey_response_value tsrv2
                         on tsrv2.response_id = tsr2.response_id
                         where tsr2.question_id in (205, 227, 278)
                         and tsrv2.value like '%Autism%'
                         or tsrv2.value like '%Autistic%'
                         or tsrv2.value like '%Asperger%');
```

Comment: Thanks.

I have a survey where we have collected information from participants 
Question 66 is free text
Question 205/227/278 captures any differences in our Texters that we might want to know 

So I want to look at the answers to question 66
for only the subset of people who answered 'Autism' etc to question 205/227/278

I think I need to create a subquery but I have been tackling this for weeks from scratch and I am stuck now.

Thanks

Comment: I have checked that and it seems correct though the .value always comes from the tsrv table, never the tsr 

So it would be?

`select tsr.conversation_id
from texter_survey_response tsr
join texter_survey_response_value tsrv on tsrv.response_id = tsr.response_id
where tsrv.question_id = 66
and **tsrv.value** =
(select tsrv1.value
 from texter_survey_response_value tsrv1
 where tsrv1.value like '%Autism%'
 or tsrv1.value like '%Autistic%'
 or tsrv1.value like '%Asperger%')`

However i run this on MYSQL and get an error: 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Comment: sorry the '.value' is only in the tsrv table and not the tsr table. 

The tsr table contains 
question_id, conversation_id and response_id only.

Whilst the tsrv table contains
response_id
question_id
and value.

I am working with an old system and cannot change the way to data fits together

Comment: Hi thanks, that's really helpful. It is pulling up data from question 66 that contains information about 'Autism', but I want it to pull up any data from question 66 where they have answered 'Autism' to question 205/227/278. I hope that makes sense. Don't worry if it doesn't make sense, I will work with what you have provided me, as that's further than I have got before. Thanks.

Comment: @jjdata I have changed the last query in my answer. Check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206517/discussion-between-vboka-and-jjdata).

Comment: `where texter_survey_response_value.question_id IN (205, 227, 278)`

So at the top, in my original question I detailed that I want to find the answer to question 66 when the answer to question 205 227 or 278 is 'Autism' - which is why I think i need a subquery